# Найти одинаковые значения в массиве объектов

Tags: javascript

Есть массив объектов типа:

```
let data = [
    { id: 1, page: 1, duplicate: false },
    { id: 2, page: 2, duplicate: false },
    { id: 3, page: 3, duplicate: false },
    { id: 4, page: 3, duplicate: false },
    { id: 5, page: 4, duplicate: false },
    { id: 6, page: 5, duplicate: false },
    { id: 7, page: 5, duplicate: false },
    { id: 8, page: 6, duplicate: false }]
```

Не могу решить 2 задачи:

1. Нужно найти все одинаковые значения "page" и изменить "duplicate" на true, то есть у объектов с ID = 3, 4, 6 и 7, значения ключа "duplicate" сделать равным true.
2. Создать новый массив со списком ID имеющих дубликаты, т.е.: [3, 4, 6, 7]

В итоге получить надо два массива:

Первый (изменённый исходный):

```
  data = [
    { id: 1, page: 1, duplicate: false },
    { id: 2, page: 2, duplicate: false },
    { id: 3, page: 3, duplicate: true },
    { id: 4, page: 3, duplicate: true  },
    { id: 5, page: 4, duplicate: false },
    { id: 6, page: 5, duplicate: true },
    { id: 7, page: 5, duplicate: true },
    { id: 8, page: 6, duplicate: false }
  ]
```

Второй, новый со списком ID:

```
duplicateIds = [3,4,6,7]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Линейное решение:

```js
let data = [
  { id: 1, page: 1, duplicate: false },
  { id: 2, page: 2, duplicate: false },
  { id: 3, page: 3, duplicate: false },
  { id: 4, page: 3, duplicate: false },
  { id: 5, page: 4, duplicate: false },
  { id: 6, page: 5, duplicate: false },
  { id: 7, page: 5, duplicate: false },
  { id: 8, page: 6, duplicate: false },
]

let count = Object.create(null)
let used = new Set()

for (let {page} of data) {
  if ((count[page] = ~~count[page] + 1) == 2) {
    used.add(page)
  }
}

let dups = []

for (let x of data) {
  if (used.has(x.page)) {
    x.duplicate = true
    dups.push(x.id)
  }
}

console.log(dups)
console.log(data)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

Comment: Ваш ответ меня сильно удивил тем, что в нём столько всего не знакомого мне, первый раз увидел двойную тильду `~~` (двойной побитовый оператор не), так же до этого не приходилось  работать с объектом `Set`, но протестировав ваш ответ вроде во всех случаях рабочий (и при дублях больше 2х и при разном порядке page)

Answer (score 1):

Возможно можно сделать намного проще, но это то на что я пока что способен ^-^
Надеюсь помог

```js
let data = [
    { id: 1, page: 1, duplicate: false },
    { id: 2, page: 2, duplicate: false },
    { id: 3, page: 3, duplicate: false },
    { id: 4, page: 3, duplicate: false },
    { id: 5, page: 4, duplicate: false },
    { id: 6, page: 5, duplicate: false },
    { id: 7, page: 5, duplicate: false },
    { id: 8, page: 6, duplicate: false }];
let duplicateIds  = [],
  temp = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  for (let j = i + 1; j < data.length; j++) {
    if (data[i]['page'] == data[j]['page']) {
      data[i]['duplicate'] = true;
      data[j]['duplicate'] = true;
      duplicateIds .push(data[i]['id'], data[j]['id']);
    }
  }
}
console.log(data);
console.log(duplicateIds );
```

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас все проверил и кое что обнаружил, вот ответ хорош только если дубликатов не больше 2х, допустим если `page: 6` повторяется 3 раза или более, то в `duplicateIds` попадаются одни и те же ID по несколько раз

Answer (score 1):

```js
let data = [
  { id: 1, page: 1, duplicate: false },
  { id: 2, page: 2, duplicate: false },
  { id: 3, page: 3, duplicate: false },
  { id: 4, page: 3, duplicate: false },
  { id: 5, page: 4, duplicate: false },
  { id: 6, page: 5, duplicate: false },
  { id: 7, page: 5, duplicate: false },
  { id: 8, page: 6, duplicate: false }
];
let duplicateIds = [];

let new_data = data.map((e,i,a) => {  
  if (a.filter((_,ind) => i != ind).some(item => item.page === e.page)) {
    duplicateIds.push(e.id);
    e.duplicate = true;
    return e;
  } else return e;
});

console.log(new_data);
console.log(duplicateIds);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [
    { id: 1, page: 1, duplicate: false },
    { id: 2, page: 2, duplicate: false },
    { id: 3, page: 3, duplicate: false },
    { id: 4, page: 3, duplicate: false },
    { id: 5, page: 4, duplicate: false },
    { id: 6, page: 5, duplicate: false },
    { id: 7, page: 5, duplicate: false },
    { id: 8, page: 6, duplicate: false }]

const duplicateIds = [];

// Считаем, что data предварительно упорядочен по возрастанию page

data.forEach( function(object, position, array) {
  if (position !== array.length - 1 && object.page === array[position + 1].page) {
    object.duplicate = true;
    array[position + 1].duplicate = true;
  }
  
  if (object.duplicate === true) duplicateIds.push(object.id);
});

console.log(data);
console.log(duplicateIds);
```